# R : discrete data not recognized (bnlearn package)

Tags: r

I have a problem in R, using bnlearn package

here are my test data (full data set is 20 000 rows):

### Data

```
>test_bis
Ohno.Duplicates disease.Y complex.Y
          0         0         0
          0         0         0
          0         1         0
          0         0         0
          0         0         0
```

### Problem

```
> test=hc(test_bis, score="bde")
Error in check.score(score, x) : 
core 'bde' may be used with discrete data only.
```

I don't understand why my data is not seen as discrete, since there are only 0 and 1. Can it be a type problem

Or more generally : How does the function decide what is "discrete"?

Comment: Have you tried to `factor()` your columns, to make them explicitly categorical?

Comment: what do you have when you run str(test_bis)?

Comment: It seems that as.factor() on each columns solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Converting numeric columns to factor solves the problem. The following piece of code converts to numeric columns to factor.

`cols <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
dat[,cols] <- lapply(dat[,cols], as.factor)`